# create view using union all in the query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a view from a single table as

```
Create view v1 as
    select severity,avg(days),count(bugid) from tabble1 where bugid in (105,109) group by severity
union all
    select severity,avg(days),count(bugid) from tabble1 where bugid in (105,109) group by severity
union all
    select severity,avg(days),count(bugid) from tabble1 where bugid in (105,109) group by severity
```

---

View is created. But when I see the data in the view (`select * from v1`) is different from when I run only the query:

```
select severity,avg(days),count(bugid) from tabble1 where bugid in (105,109)group by severity
union all
select severity,avg(days),count(bugid) from tabble1 where bugid in (105,109)group by severity
union all
select severity,avg(days),count(bugid) from tabble1 where bugid in (105,109)group by severity
```

What may be the reason and how to resolve this?
Thanks.

Comment: How are the results different?

Comment: And are you really doing a `union` of the same query 3 times?

Comment: Are you really sure that the complete data set is different (independent of the order)?

Comment: in each select there is a calculation for getting data for previous month. for example first select produces data for the current month, second select gives the previuos month data and third on gives the previuos to previuos month data. I am using Union All. AvgDays, count(BudId) are different in view which is wrong. While I run only the sql query it gives correct result.

Comment: @OceanView Ok, so the queries that you posted aren't the same as the queries that you're having an issue with.  It will be impossible for us to tell you what is wrong if we don't have an accurate picture of your issue.

Comment: ok. this is a 200 lines query. so I didn't write the days calculation part in the query.

Comment: So how do you know all 200 lines are the same?

Comment: only date calculation part is different, otherwise all lines are same. I wish I could paste my SQL here. It doesn't allow me to paste that big SQL. It says my comments is 9875 characters long. If anyone can help me please provide your email id I email to you my coding and outputs of the view and the SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely possibilities that I can see:

- Your view and your query are in fact not exactly the same. Likely
  there is a  typo in one of them.
- You are running the select from the view on one server and the
  specific query on another (If I had a dollar for eveytime I was on
  the wrong server when I manually ran a query...)
- The data changed in the time between running the select against the
  view and the other select.

Comment: I'll take A for $1000 Alex!

Comment: Thanks for you answer.There is no typo in any of them. Both are running in the same server. Data in that table doesn't change in every 5 minutes or frequently. So there may be some other reason.